# Add the values of several columns when the number of columns exceeds 3 - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns of dates, numbers and bill amounts. I would like to add the amounts of the other invoices with the 3rd one and change the invoice number by "1111".
Here is an example:

| ID customer | Bill1 | Date 1 | ID Bill 1 | Bill2 | Date 2 | ID Bill 2 | Bill3 | Date3 | ID Bill 3 | Bill4 | Date 4 | ID Bill 4 | Bill5 | Date 5 | ID Bill 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 2000-10-04 | 1 | 45 | 2000-11-05 | 2 | 51 | 1999-12-05 | 3 | 23 | 2001-11-23 | 6 | 76 | 2011-08-19 | 12 |
| 6 | 8 | 2016-05-03 | 7 | 39 | 2017-08-09 | 8 | 38 | 2018-07-14 | 17 | 21 | 2009-05-04 | 9 | Nan | Nan | Nan |
| 12 | 14 | 2016-11-16 | 10 | 73 | 2017-05-04 | 15 | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan | Nan |

And I would like to get this :

| ID customer | Bill1 | Date 1 | ID Bill 1 | Bill2 | Date 2 | ID Bill 2 | Bill3 | Date3 | ID Bill 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 2000-10-04 | 1 | 45 | 2000-11-05 | 2 | 150 | 1999-12-05 | 1111 |
| 6 | 8 | 2016-05-03 | 7 | 39 | 2017-08-09 | 8 | 59 | 2018-07-14 | 1111 |
| 12 | 14 | 2016-11-16 | 10 | 73 | 2017-05-04 | 15 | Nan | Nan | Nan |

This example is a sample of my data, I may have many more than 5 columns.
Thanks for your help

Comment: what is the logic?where are you adding?all I see is 1111 in place of  previous values of ID Bill 3!! can you pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a little of data manipulation, you should be able to do it as:

```
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)
idx_col_bill3 = 7
step = 3
idx_col_bill3_id = 10
cols = df.columns

bills = df[cols[range(idx_col_bill3,len(cols), step)]].sum(axis=1)
bills.replace(0, nan, inplace=True)
df = df[cols[range(idx_col_bill3_id)]]
df['Bill3'] = bills
df['ID Bill 3'].iloc._setitem_with_indexer(df['ID Bill 3'].notna(),1111)
```